# App icon is visible in splash screen with launching image in iOS

Tags: ios

I am facing a problem from last 3 days. When my app is launching, icon image also coming with launch image in splash screen. My launching image name is : **Default.png** and Icon name is: **57x57.png** and my *launching image bg is transparent*.

When app is launching that time icon and launching image both are visible. Please anybody help me how to fix this issue.

I am adding icon like this:

in plist file

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the assets? (images.xcassets)

Comment: ya i checked properly

Comment: Maybe research (using the search ^^) the photo name in your code, maybe you're setting it up programatically somewhere? I'm guessing you checkde that 100 times already but i'm just trying to shoot out ideas

Answer (score 1):

You can't make it transparent. It must fill up with colour. If you make it transparent, black colour will appear.

Comment: ya thats no problem with black colour. But my problem is why icon image is coming backside of launching image?